# How to generate authkey for python BaseManager

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started looking at Python's multiprocessing and was interested in distributed processing.   On the python website it shows code similar to the following:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
manager = BaseManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abc')
server = manager.get_server()
server.serve_forever()
```

and

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
m = BaseManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey=b'abc')
m.connect()
```

I tried creating two scripts for each piece of code and then running them.   I changed the 127.0.0.1 to my computers IP address.

I currently don't know how to setup an authkey, so tried using None, but I am getting a large error including the statement: 'digest sent was rejected'

If possible, could you help answer the following:

1. Is there a simple way to get the 2 scripts communicating with each other without using authkey ?
2. How do you create an authkey.   I am currently using a Mac, sometimes I use Windows and I am aware that lots of people use Linux, so would it be possible to answer this for all three operating systems ?
3. The doc's gave me the impression that the Firewall may cause problems.   I doubt this is the cause of my current problem, but if you have any suggestions on how to make this work when I work on multiple computers, that would be great.
4. If you have any more tip's it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the Mac, I found this video by Peter Upfold useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTmNXBgNMUU

I will post more details when I get around to using it on a pc/linux etc.